# Error while processing content unencoding: incorrect header check

Tags: php, compression, apache2, gzip, symfony5

I am trying to set a global header when returning each response from my app, so as per `symfony5` guidelines I have created an event listener and registered it.

**src\EventListener\RequestListener.php**

```php
<?php

namespace App\Api\EventListener;

use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Event\ResponseEvent;

class RequestListener {
    public function onKernelResponse(ResponseEvent $responseEvent) {
        if (!$responseEvent->isMasterRequest()) {
            return;
        }

        /** @var Response $response */
        $response = $responseEvent->getResponse();
        $response->headers->set('Content-Encoding', 'gzip');
    }
}
```

**config/services.yaml**

```yaml
App\Api\EventListener\RequestListener:
    class: App\Api\EventListener\RequestListener
    tags:
        - { name: kernel.event_listener, event: 'kernel.response', method: 'onKernelResponse' }
```

But the problem is whenever I try to call any endpoint on the app, I keep getting the error `Error while processing content unencoding: incorrect header check` as seen in the screenshots below

[image]
[image]

How can I go about solving this issue?

Comment: And where/how are you actually encoding your responses as `gzip`?

Comment: @CBroe How do you mean?

Comment: You are adding a header telling the client, that the content it has received was gzip-encoded. So where are you actually performing that encoding? If you don't - well then you just _lied_ to the client.

Comment: @CBroe And that is where I need help. How do I go about solving the issue, as stated?

Answer (score 0):

I finally managed to solve the issue by add the following to the `public/.htaccess` file

```
<IfModule mod_deflate.c>
    SetOutputFilter DEFLATE
    SetEnvIfNoCase Request_URI "\.(?:gif|jpe?g|png)$" no-gzip
</IfModule>
```

And then I got rid of the code I had written earlier to set the response headers.